# define a message key in <exception-mapping>?

Tags: struts2

I'm trying to find a way to configure in struts.xml an error message for each type of exception that can be thrown by an Action class.  In an action class I could accomplish something similar by catching an exception, calling `addActionError(String)`, and rethrowing the exception (provided an `<exception-mapping>` exists).  Is there a way to do this through configuration?

As a reference point, this functionality exists in Struts1 with the `key` attribute on an exception handler - I'm hoping to be able to do something similar.

```
<exception key="some.key"
           type="java.io.IOException"
           handler="com.yourcorp.ExceptionHandler"/>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Struts2 isn't a newer version of Struts1 -- they're completely different frameworks that happen to share the same name. With that said, if you give a little more detail about what you want to accomplish, then perhaps someone can point out a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In strut2 also you can define exception mappings. Refer http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/exception-configuration.html. You can have a common error.jsp which displays a message that is looked up based on the class name of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

In Struts2 you can use the following mapping to pass on the key/message to result (result can be a jsp or another action class).

```
<global-exception-mappings>
 <exception-mapping exception="com.test.exception.MyCustomException"  result="error">
    <param name="param">display.custom.error</param>
 </exception-mapping>
</global-exception-mappings>

<global-results>
    <result name="error" type="chain">handleAction</result>
</global-results>

<action name="handleAction" class="HandleExceptionAction">          
     <result name="result">/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

If it an action class, in case of chaining (if the user wants to process the exception) then you need to have a corresponding attribute in Action class with getters and setters.

```
public class HandleExceptionAction extends ActionSupport implements 
               ServletRequestAware, SessionAware {

private **String param**; 

private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(InputAction.class); 

public String execute(){

    LOG.debug("inside excute().....");
    LOG.debug("Parameter passed:" + param);
    System.out.println("Parameter passed:" + param);

    return "result";
}
```

I am using spring injection, hope it will hep you.